# SonicWall and Windows CA

Tags: sonicwall

I'm attempting to import a certificate created by a CA I've set up in Windows using AD CS. I've done the following:

1) Created my own CA (MyCompany)
2) Enabled web services (mostly for ease of configuration)
3) Generated a certificate request on the Sonicwall itself
4) Used web services to sign the certificate
5) Imported the sign certificate into the Sonicwall ...this caused the certificate to show "No" for the Verified field.
6) Imported the CA's certificate.

This is where I get stuck. I attempted to import the CRL list, but get the following error: `CRL Error - Verification failed using CA certificate`. No further errors appear in the logs. Without the CRL list the certificate won't verify and it doesn't appear under the "Administration" page so I can select it for use via HTTPS.

Any ideas?

Edit: From Sonicwall when I attempt to use my HTTP published list:

```
07/02/2013 14:33:54.256 Alert   VPN PKI Cannot Validate Issuer Path         HTTPS        
19  07/02/2013 14:33:54.256 Alert   VPN PKI CRL validation failure for Root Certificate         MyCompanyCA      
20  07/02/2013 14:33:54.256 Alert   VPN PKI Failed to Process CRL from           http://crl.mydomain.com/Cert
Enroll/ CA: MyCompanyCA
```

Comment: Why not make a CRL available? You should have it anyway

Comment: Agreed. You need to add an HTTP CRL Distribution Point to your certs, in addition to the LDAP one.

Comment: @RyanRies I added one, but it's failing to process at this point.

Comment: @NathanC Did you do it *exactly* like this? http://blogs.technet.com/b/mspfe/archive/2013/04/24/adcs-manually-created-cdp-extensions-cause-crl-look-up-failures.aspx

:)

Comment: @RyanRies Yes. Changed the path - still the same problem. Updating my question with new errors.

Comment: Bummer, I was hoping to hit it out of the park with that. :(

Comment: Are you using a root certificate or an intermediate to create the Sonicwall cert?  If you're using an intermediate, can/did you try and import both the intermediate and the root cert to the Sonicwall?

Comment: When you captured that bit in your edit from the Sonicwall's log (the whole "PKI Failed to Process CRL from..." bit) did you compare that to the logs on the web server publishing the CRL to see if it actually attempted to download the CRL?

Comment: @PaulKroon I used the root cert.

Comment: @EvanAnderson Interestingly enough, no. It *did* hit the server a couple times when I was first trying to get it working, but after that the logs were silent. I used the certutil and it worked on my Windows machine, though.

Comment: @NathanC I know you mentioned you validated the CRL with certutil, but as an added check, can you copy the HTTP url listed and actually browse to it to make sure the .crl file gets downloaded?  It might just be the log formatting, but it looks like the Sonicwall doesn't see an actual .crl file in the url.

Comment: @PaulKroon Yes, the CRL downloads.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, after coming back to this with a brand new CA, it appears there's actually a [bug](http://www.sonicwall.com/us/en/support/2213.html?fuzeurl=http://www.fuzeqna.com/sonicwallkb/ext/kbdetail.aspx?kbid=10380&SearchType=advanced&referrer=&status=&rfield=&sortmethod=datemodified&usertype=&subcats=True&start=1&viewguid=E425BAE5-A68B-405D-86FB-36D8FB1FEA78&match=and&catid=454&formaction=amq) with SonicOS 5.8 that causes this issue. My CA certificate is SHA512 and SonicOS only supports SHA1. Unfortunately I can't upgrade to 5.9 yet (which resolves the issue). If this helps anyone else, awesome.

Answer (score 0):

Well, doing wild guesses, lets do this:

- lets start with the stupid thing: are you sure you are importing the correct file?!  :)
- Are the DNS correct? Can the sonicwall resolve successful the crl.mydomain.com ?
- Is time correct? make sure you have a ntp server configured in both sides, usually certificates management require correct time.
- Does the crl url really downloads anything?
- Can you see the windows CA logs, to confirm that the file is downloaded? or even better, load a sniffer (like wireshark) in the windows CA and see if you get any request, on what port you get the request and what you reply back. If you get nothing, check firewall, routing problems, acl , etc

If you get a request and reply successful with valid info, it's  probably a sonicwall problem.

If all fails, open a service request to SonicWall, they should help you debug the problem

Comment: Weirdly enough, no request is made to the CA. I can however ping the CA and I can use `certutil` to validate the CRL from my own local machine. Both are on the same subnet too. It's really odd. Wireshark will probably be my only chance in this case.